# How to query data from subquery table in typeorm

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm, query-builder

Here is what I want:

```
select * from (
    select requester_id, CASE
        WHEN requester_id = 'f791283d-43fd-484c-b11b-3360f436437c' THEN addressee_id
        WHEN addressee_id = 'f791283d-43fd-484c-b11b-3360f436437c' THEN requester_id
        END as coworker_id 
    from coworker_relations
) as i
join users on user_id = coworker_id
```

Here is the code:

```
const subquery = this.createQueryBuilder('coworker_relations')
      .select('requester_id')
      .addSelect(`CASE
        WHEN requester_id = '${requester_id}' THEN addressee_id
        WHEN addressee_id = '${requester_id}' THEN requester_id
        END 
      `, 'coworker_id')
    const query = this.createQueryBuilder()
      .select("*")
      .from(`(${ subquery.getQuery() })`, "coworkers_table")
    return query.getRawMany();
```

Here is what I get:

```
SELECT * FROM "coworker_relations" "coworkers_table", (SELECT requester_id, CASE
        WHEN requester_id = 'f791283d-43fd-484c-b11b-3360f436437c' THEN addressee_id
        WHEN addressee_id = 'f791283d-43fd-484c-b11b-3360f436437c' THEN requester_id
        END
       AS "coworker_id" FROM "coworker_relations" "coworker_relations") "coworkers_table"
```

What I want is to have `select * from coworkers_table` not `coworker_relations`, how to achieve this?